# Pandas : Import multiple excel files in a single data frame, perform operations one by one and print the output in a single csv file

Tags: python, excel, pandas, csv, data-analysis

> Three questions within a single piece of code.

I have quite a lot of excel files which follow a similar pattern in their nomenclature, e.g `Design__Tolerance_1.xlsx`, `Design_Tolerance_2.xlsx`, etc. kept in one folder

Let's consider the first file `Design__Tolerance_1.xlsx` as
 [image: this]

I am reading the first three columns of the excel file in my python program using the Pandas module as follows

```
fields = ['Time', 'Test 1', 'Test 2']
df=pd.read_excel('Design_Tolerance_1.xlsx', skipinitialspace=True, 
usecols=fields)
```

Next, I am finding the mean of the column `Test 1` and maximum value of the column `Test 2`

```
mean_value = df['Test 1'].mean()
max_value = df['Test 2'].mean()
```

And, I am printing the output in a seperate `.csv` file.

```
columns=["MEAN","MAX"]
data_under_columns = {"MEAN":[mean_value], "MAXIMUM VALUE":[max_value]}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data_under_columns, columns=columns)
```

The file `output_file.csv` will contain the output

```
df1.to_csv('output_file.csv', sep=",",  index = False)
```

Could you help me do the following:

1. I have kept all my files in same folder and I want the program to read all the files having the nomenclature pattern as mentioned above (`Design__Tolerance_1.xlsx`, `Design_Tolerance_2.xlsx`, etc.) in the same dataframe `df` , the program  should run as many times as the number of files are there.
2. Let's say I have **four excel files** following the same naming pattern (`Design__Tolerance_XXX.xlsx`) present in the folder, I want the program to run **four times** and calculate the mean of the column `Test 1` and maximum value of the column `Test 2` for all the files one after another; and
3. Print only one **`.csv`** file as `output_file.csv` which contains the output from all the excel files.
   e.g.

[image: Like this]

Use of functions are acceptable too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do something like that. This solution is going to go through all your folder, and for every xlsx file, it is going to create a record with the mean and the max value, and once it is done, it is going to create a dataframe with one line per file, and store it as a csv.

```
# std
import glob

# 3rd
import pandas as pd

# Select all the files in your directory
directory = r'path/to/your/directory'
files = glob.glob(directory + "/*.xlsx")
fields = ["Test 1", "Test 2"]
records = []

for f in files:
    # Every file is put in a temp dataframe, and operations are performed
    temp_df = pd.read_excel(f, skipinitialspace=True, usecols=fields)
    mean_value = temp_df['Test 1'].mean()
    max_value = temp_df['Test 2'].max()
    records.append((mean_value, max_value))

# Finally, we create a dataframe with our records and we store it
df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(records, columns=['MEAN', 'MAX'])
df.to_csv('output_file.csv', sep=',',  index=False)
```

Comment: It's showing me error in the line `directory = 'path/to/your/directory'` when I'm trying to run the program. 

SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes in position 2-3: truncated \UXXXXXXXX escape

Comment: Sorry, in line `files = ...` replace `path` by `directory`

Comment: Are you on Windows ? If so, try this : `directory = r'path/to/your/directory'`

Comment: In the output `.csv` file, I'm just getting the headers 'MEAN' and 'MAX', there are no values under the column

Comment: Hum, I tried with CSV files and it worked on my side. Can you try to print the value of mean and max during every step of the loop. Also the content of records before putting it in the dataframe

Comment: Yes, I can try that. 
Print the mean and max inside the loop and the records outside of it.

Comment: Use  `print (mean_value,'\t')` and  `print (max_value,'\n')`